# Broadcast receiver to read incoming sms

Tags: android-studio, android-broadcastreceiver

My app to read incoming sms using broadcast receiver is working fine in many mobiles but not working in samsung j5 mobile. Can you give me proper solution for that problem.
My `MainActivity.java` is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyReceiver.bindListener(new SmsListener.OTPListener() {
               @Override
               public void messageReceived(String messageText, String messageSender) {
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"message is "+messageText+ " and sender is "+messageSender ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           });
   }
}
```

`MyReceiver.java`

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static SmsListener.OTPListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)) {

        Bundle data  = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] pdus = new Object[0];
        if(data != null)
        {
            pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
        }
        if(pdus != null)
        {
            for(Object pdu : pdus ){
                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdu);
                String sender = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                if (mListener!=null)
                {
                    mListener.messageReceived(messageBody, sender);
                    break;
                }        
            }
        }
    }

    public static void bindListener(SmsListener.OTPListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static void unbindListener() {
        mListener = null;
    }
}
```

`SmsListener.java`

```
public interface SmsListener {
    interface OTPListener{
        void messageReceived(String messageText,String messageSender);
    }
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.aaa.aaa">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/b"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/b"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:priority="2147483647"
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
            >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my application code. I want to toast the message and sender when a new message is arrived (even app is killed or destroyed), but in samsung j5 mobile, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into a permission issue. The Samsung J5 is an older Samsung model, so I assume your other "mobiles" are also older phones running older android releases. Which leads me to think that you maybe running into a permission issue with the J5 as it would probably be running a newer android release. Here is how you can get [permission](https://android.jlelse.eu/detecting-sending-sms-on-android-8a154562597f) to read SMS on newer android releases!

Comment: Permission is not issue because this mobile have lollipop android version and i checked my app in other mobile which have kitkat , lollipop & marshmallow version and app works fine for me.

Comment: Well, without your app's code, it is impossible for anyone to help you!

Comment: Now, i added my application code. what is wrong in code.